# Default assembly revision number always 0 in F# assemblies

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, f#, versioning

If I specify that I want the default build and revision numbers, I put

```
[<assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.0.*")>]
```

in AssemblyInfo.fs (which I based on the sample at https://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2011/06/01/f-assembly-information-file-template.aspx).

For some reason, I always end up with revision number 0 (e.g. `0.0.4967.0`) in F# DLLs, while it works as advertised in C# (e.g. `0.0.4967.21937`).

Default revision numbers only work when the build number is not a wildcard, `0.0.1.*`.

Is this a bug or have I missed something?

Comment: I just verified that this bug is still present in VS2013.

Comment: ...but gone in VS2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug.  It works as advertised in VS 2010 (F# 2.0, for which that blog was written) but is broken in VS 2012 (F# 3.0) and VS 2013 (F# 3.1, still pre-release).  You should send a bug report to fsbugs@microsoft.com.

The code for F# 2.0 is down at the bottom of il.fs [here](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#compiler/2.0/Nov2010/src/absil/il.fs).  Look for `parseILVersion`.

Corresponding code for 3.0 is [here](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#compiler/3.0/Sep2012/src/absil/il.fs).

The bug is in the new conditionals - they check  `versionComponents.Length < 4`, should probably be checking `version.Revision < 0`.